# Specific quaternary quartic that is positive semi-definite but not sum of squares

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry, sums-of-squares, positivity

Does there exist a quaternary quartic $f$ (a form in $\mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ of degree $4$), which is positive semi-definite ($f \geq 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$) but not a sum of squares, such that one variable in $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ has only even exponents?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is such an example in [Choi, Positive semidefinite biquadratic forms, §4]. It is proven there that the polynomial 
$$x^4+y^4-2(x^2+y^2)zw+z^2w^2+2(x^2z^2+y^2w^2)$$
is positive semidefinite, but not a sum of squares.